# How to solve this error in GATK: A USER ERROR has occurred: Machine does not support OpenMP AVX PairHMM

Tags: openmp, avx

I am running GATK HAPLOTYPECALLER both with snakemake and as a command line on my Ubuntu 16.04 version, gatk-4.1.9.0 version:

> Tools/gatk/gatk --java-options "-Xmx16g -XX:ParallelGCThreads=10"
> HaplotypeCaller -R ref.fasta -I recal.bam  -O outfile.vcf
> --min-base-quality-score 20 --minimum-mapping-quality 20 -pairHMM AVX_LOGLESS_CACHING_OMP

This continues giving me the following error and I cannot find a solution for some days now...Any ideas how to solve this?

> A USER ERROR has occurred: Machine does not support OpenMP AVX
> PairHMM.
>
> *********************************************************************** org.broadinstitute.hellbender.exceptions.UserException$HardwareFeatureException:
> Machine does not support OpenMP AVX PairHMM.
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.utils.pairhmm.VectorLoglessPairHMM.(VectorLoglessPairHMM.java:77)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.utils.pairhmm.PairHMM$Implementation.lambda$static$4(PairHMM.java:63)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.utils.pairhmm.PairHMM$Implementation.makeNewHMM(PairHMM.java:119)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.tools.walkers.haplotypecaller.PairHMMLikelihoodCalculationEngine.(PairHMMLikelihoodCalculationEngine.java:152)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.tools.walkers.haplotypecaller.AssemblyBasedCallerUtils.createLikelihoodCalculationEngine(AssemblyBasedCallerUtils.java:204)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.tools.walkers.haplotypecaller.HaplotypeCallerEngine.initialize(HaplotypeCallerEngine.java:243)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.tools.walkers.haplotypecaller.HaplotypeCallerEngine.(HaplotypeCallerEngine.java:186)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.tools.walkers.haplotypecaller.HaplotypeCaller.onTraversalStart(HaplotypeCaller.java:259)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.engine.GATKTool.doWork(GATKTool.java:1055)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.cmdline.CommandLineProgram.runTool(CommandLineProgram.java:140)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.cmdline.CommandLineProgram.instanceMainPostParseArgs(CommandLineProgram.java:192)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.cmdline.CommandLineProgram.instanceMain(CommandLineProgram.java:211)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.Main.runCommandLineProgram(Main.java:160)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.Main.mainEntry(Main.java:203)
> at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.Main.main(Main.java:289)

EDIT: On both other PC's that have UBUNTU v.18.04 this is working, is this something correlated to ubuntu version?
EDIT: I cannot install anything on that PC as I do not have root permission. But I can install using conda.

Comment: AFAICT that error message is saying that the code has been compiled to run on a machine with (some unspecified level of) AVX support, whereas the hardware on which it is running does not support that set of instructions. So you need to consider the CPU models. Look in /proc/cpuinfo (or use "lscpu") to see the differences, and what instruction set enhancements are supported by each one.

Comment: Is your PC old, or running in a VM that disables AVX?  Or is it running on a Celeron or Pentium?  Those don't have AVX.  (`grep -o avx /proc/cpuinfo` in Linux will show you if AVX is supported by the CPU.)

Comment: So, in case the reason is one the one's you listed, it is NOT possible at all to solve this, do I understand right?

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to use AVX_LOGLESS_CACHING_OMP? From what I see [here](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360037225632-HaplotypeCaller) the choice of pairHMM is just an implementation detail. I would just go for whatever works...!

Comment: No particular reason, but when I tested one bam file processing with AVX_LOGLESS_CACHING_OMP it took 2 hours, with LOGLESS_CACHING (which it uses in case AMP doesn't work) it takes 3 hours... If I have 500 samples, this can become a significant saving of time...